# JavaScript form validation working unexpectedly and printing undefined

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I was trying to write a simple Vanilla JS function which would check if user has left any form fields empty and if that's the case, then alert the user. Unfortunately, it doesn't quite work and I don't know why.

[image: Picture of form]

As, you can see it says "undefined can't be left empty".

Here's the JS Code:

```
var username= document.getElementById("UsernameInput");
var email= document.getElementById("EmailInput");
var pass= document.getElementById("PasswordInput");
var confirmPass= document.getElementById("ConfirmPasswordInput");
var form= document.querySelector(".registration-form");

// Function for checking empty input 
function checkEmpty(inputArr){
  for(i=0;i<inputArr.length;i++){
    if(inputArr[i].value.trim()==='')
      var stringified= JSON.stringify(inputArr[i]);
      alert(`${stringified} can't be left empty`);
      console.log(inputArr[i]);
      break;
  }
}

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  
  if(checkEmpty([username,email,pass,confirmPass]));
    e.preventDefault();
 
 
})
```

So, why is the "stringified" variable undefined? (I'm using JSON.stringify because when I was not doing that it was returning [object object]).

Here's the HTML for the form:

```
<form action="#" class="registration-form ">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="six columns  ">
          <label for="username">Your username (has to be unique)</label>
          <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="redditStar" id="UsernameInput" name="username">
        </div>
      </div>
      
   
   <div class="row">
    <div class="six columns">
      <label for="email">Your email</label>
      <input class="u-full-width" type="email" placeholder="test@emailcom" id="EmailInput" name="email">
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="six columns">
      <label for="password">Your password</label>
      <input class="u-full-width" type="password" placeholder="Enter a strong password" id="PasswordInput" name="password">
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="six columns">
      <label for="confirm-password">Confirm your Password</label>
      <input class="u-full-width" type="password" placeholder="Confirm password.." id="ConfirmPasswordInput" name="passwordConfirm">
    </div>
   </div>
    
  <input class="button-primary submitRegister" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Comment: `inputArr[i]` is the `<input>` element. For the error message you'll want its `.name`. Don't just use `JSON.stringify` arbitrarily without understanding what it does.

Comment: @Guy Incognito the field's name that is left empty.

Comment: So you want to print `inputArr[i].name`?

Comment: Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/ktw54goj/

Comment: inputArr[i].name fixed it but it was also giving the alerts for fields not empty. Dylan's suggestion of using curly braces then helped with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your if statement in the for.

```js
for(i=0;i<inputArr.length;i++){
    if(inputArr[i].value.trim()==='')
      var stringified= JSON.stringify(inputArr[i]);
      alert(`${stringified} can't be left empty`);
      console.log(inputArr[i]);
      break;
  }
```

Following javascript's indentation rules when your if lacks curly braces, if expression is true only the next line is run. If it's false, it skips the next line. So, when that if is false, it jumps to ``` alert(``${stringified} can't be left empty``); ``` which stringified is undefined since it was not defined on the line before.

Comment: It'll still "work" because `var`s are hoisted. This is not the real issue here.

Comment: AFAIK, yes, the declaration is hoisted, but the definition is not.

Comment: thanks it works now.. I just had to use inputArr[i].name and the curly braces on if like you said